# Multi-home Utillity Alley Potholes - fix it my self or is there someone to call?

Tags: repair, driveway, utilities

Ive recently bought a house that has a service alley in the back leading to parking. Its a no outlet alley servicing about 4-6 houses (mostly rented) which is probably why it hasn't been properly maintained.

The potholes are on the verge of being "tub"holes if youre catching my drift.

Should i fill them with gravel for the time being or is there someone i can call to fix them?

Comment: Do you have a homeowners' association (HOA)? The alley must be owned by someone: if not by the municipality, then by the HOA. Or it's owned in condominium, or something like that, depending on how the community is organized.

Comment: @Mike Harris - no HOA, must be the municipality. Would i just have to contact roadworks or something of that nature?

Comment: Who's responsible to fix the road gets into a legal ownership question that bordering on off topic here. You'd need to call your landlord or local municipality to work that out. The proper steps to fix this on your own property would be a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step will be determining who owns the land. I'd start by contacting the landlord, as they should know who owns the land. Depending on where you live, the city/town hall should have lot surveys (these are required at the time of sale, in some areas). So if the landlord doesn't know who owns it, you should be able to look it up.

If it's an easement, maintenance likely falls to the property owner.  If it's outright owned by a utility, then it should be the utilities responsibility.  In all cases, it's almost never a renters responsibility.